# I'm having trouble installing CMake -- For some reason it says it can't create a folder

Tags: unix, ubuntu, cmake

So here's the thing -- I'm trying to install CMake (and the installation was almost complete too) but then it showed this message:

CMake Error at cmake_install.cmake:36 (file):
  file cannot create directory: /usr/local/doc/cmake-3.7.  Maybe need
  administrative privileges.

Screen shot:
since stack overflow won't let me post images, here's a link:
https://s13.postimg.org/8vygwqiwn/Screenshot_from_2016_11_04_17_39_11.png

But the thing is, I am the admin. Does anyone know what that problem is?

Comment: Why do you attempt to do a wild install into the file system instead of using your package management system to install `cmake`?

Comment: Well I thought thats what I was suppose to do from what it said here: https://cmake.org/install/

Comment: The first approach you _always_ should take when installation software on todays Linux distributions is to select packages from the provided repositories by using your systems software management system. That guarantees that the package you install is compatible and that all upgrades, requirements and dependencies are taken care of now and in future. If those repositories do _not_ offer a prepared package (they obviously _do_ offer `cmake`), then you should take a look for a package macthing your operating systems. Only if that also fails, _then_ a wild installation might make sense.

Comment: @arkascha Well I was told and know from experience that most of the time the package management system (lets just call it the pms) doesn't always come with the most up-to-date software.

Comment: Well, CMake 3.7 is not even released, so it will be hard to find it packaged. I advice you to not install it, but use the absolute path to your cmake build dir. If you insist on installing it, use some sub-folder in `/opt` and include it in your PATH.

Comment: Do you have enough space left on your system partition?

Comment: @Bored That is true, however there are only extremely rare cases where you really have a reason to insist to install "the latest" version of a software. If you really need to, however, then still the best approach in my experience is to take a source package of an older version, inject the new code and rebuild the package with the new version. That way you can still enjoy all the benefits of a software management which you sacrifice knowingly otherwise.

Comment: @arkascha Well I guess safe and buggy is better than confusing and (slightly less) buggy.

Comment: @ usr1234567 Yes, 480 GB's. Why?

Comment: @Bored Not being able to write could indicate missing rights or not enough space left.

Comment: Have you tried to create this directory **by yourself**? E.g., `mkdir -p /usr/local/doc/cmake-3.7`?

Answer (score 0):

The directory you're trying to install to, "/usr/local", is owned by root, not the user you're operating as. Install CMake with `sudo`: `sudo make install`.

As mentioned in the comments though, you *should* use the CMake provided by Ubuntu. Ubuntu 16.04 provides CMake v3.5.1.